# prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command - issue on during angular installation

Tags: node.js, angular

Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.16299.309]
(c) 2017 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\Futluz>cd desktop/angular-cli-master/angular-cli-master

C:\Users\Futluz\Desktop\angular-cli-master\angular-cli-master>npm install -g @angular/cli

**'CALL "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" prefix -g' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.**

Answer (score 1):

Main problem "some file path is missing in environment variables "

If you have an issue like this , 
you simply reset the windows settings

Goto *Control panel -> update & security -> recovery settings -> remove my files only*

After that you have install whatever software you need :)