# Got error while installing npm install -g @angular/Cli

Tags: node.js, angular-cli, node-modules, npm-install, angular-cli-v6

D:\CDAC Project\Nodejs>npm install -g @angular/cli

```
npm WARN deprecated request@2.88.2: request has been deprecated, see https://github.com/request/request/issues/3142
npm WARN deprecated har-validator@5.1.5: this library is no longer supported
C:\Users\Akash Tawade\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng -> C:\Users\Akash Tawade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli\bin\ng

> @angular/cli@10.0.8 postinstall C:\Users\Akash Tawade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular\cli
> node ./bin/postinstall/script.js

'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @angular/cli@10.0.8 postinstall: `node ./bin/postinstall/script.js`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @angular/cli@10.0.8 postinstall script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Akash Tawade\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2020-08-31T07_54_44_998Z-debug.log
```

I had went through many articles to solve this error as well as you tube videos but it's not working.

Comment: This might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56523652/unable-to-install-angular-cli

Comment: I tried this solution but It's not working @Aminudin

Answer (score 1):

Just add the following tags to your command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli --unsafe-perm=true --allow-root
```

Comment: This worked for me when installing Node through NVM.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same error when running the same command: `npm i -g @angular/cli`.

Node.js was installed by my company.

PowerShell recognizes `node` and `npm` commands, but CMD does not.

So I can run `npm` command from PS, but there is a moment when it tries to execute a command like this:

```
...\cmd.exe /c node ./bin/postinstall/script.js
```

and then I get the error:

```
'node' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.
```

My problem was a single quote sign `"` in environment variable PATH which broke half of PATH's paths that were after the quote sign.

I would just fix the variable, even if I had to use registry editor,
but this time it is my company's laptop without admin access so the only quick fix for me is to use https://cmder.net

Cmder seems to correct the environment variable PATH.

It removed quote sign and it understands `node` and `npm` commands.

And, yes, I just installed Angular cli using Cmder.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution that I found

Solution:-

Step 1: Uninstall angular/cli if it is already install

```
npm uninstall -g @angular/cli
```

Step 2: Try to delete folder of following if it is still present

```
C:\Users\Akash Tawade\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\@angular
```

Step 3: Try to delete file 'ng' and 'ng.cmd' if it is present.You will find these file inside below folder.

```
C:\Users\Akash Tawade\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng 

C:\Users\Akash Tawade\AppData\Roaming\npm\ng.cmd
```

Step 4: Install angular/cli globally again

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```